# How to use Redux 4.0 TypeScript bindings with redux-thunk

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm having trouble using the new TS bindings for Redux 4.0 with redux-thunk.  I've recreated the issue by converting the basic Redux ["Todo List" example](https://redux.js.org/basics/example-todo-list) to TypeScript ([repo here](https://github.com/jakeboone02/redux-4-thunk-typescript/)), and making the Add Todo action a thunk.  The problem is the same as reported [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/pull/180/files#r173176067): *Argument of type 'ThunkAction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
Property 'type' is missing in type 'ThunkAction'*.

Basically, I can get it to work, but I'm using `any` in a couple of places where I don't think I should.  One place is [index.tsx#L14](https://github.com/jakeboone02/redux-4-thunk-typescript/blob/master/src/index.tsx#L14), where I add the thunk middleware to the store:

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk as ThunkMiddleware<IRootState, any>)
);
```

If I use anything other than `any` there, then the next line throws the error:

```
store.dispatch(addTodo('Use redux-thunk'));
```

The other place is [AddTodo.tsx#L7](https://github.com/jakeboone02/redux-4-thunk-typescript/blob/master/src/containers/AddTodo.tsx#L7), where I declare the dispatch prop which is injected by the `connect` function:

```
interface IAddTodoProps {
  dispatch: Dispatch<any>;
}

const AddTodo = ({ dispatch }: IAddTodoProps) => {
  ...
}
export default connect()(AddTodo);
```

In both places, the `any` overrides a type that must extend `Action<any>`.  `Action` requires a `type` attribute, which of course a thunk does not have.  How can I declare these types so that the `dispatch` function accepts a thunk?

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49907244/redux-thunk-with-typescript)
[Relevant PR](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/pull/180)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question (and many others) turned out to be: use [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/).

The store setup is dead simple:

```
// src/redux/store.ts
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import reducer from './reducers';

const store = configureStore({ reducer });

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export default store;
```

Then when using the `useDispatch` hook from `react-redux`, just type it as `AppDispatch`:

```
// src/components/App.tsx
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { AppDispatch } from '../redux/store';

const App = () => {
  const dispatch: AppDispatch = useDispatch();
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
diff --git a/src/containers/AddTodo.tsx b/src/containers/AddTodo.tsx
index e49ac4a..20a93d6 100644
--- a/src/containers/AddTodo.tsx
+++ b/src/containers/AddTodo.tsx
@@ -1,10 +1,12 @@
 import * as React from 'react';
 import { connect } from 'react-redux';
-import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
+import { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';
+import { AnyAction } from 'redux';
 import { addTodo } from '../actions';
+import { IRootState } from '../reducers/index';

 interface IAddTodoProps {
-  dispatch: Dispatch<any>;
+  dispatch: ThunkDispatch<IRootState,any,AnyAction>;
 }

 const AddTodo = ({ dispatch }: IAddTodoProps) => {
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really get rid of the `any`s